# Unknown system name showing up in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Ive been working on some command line stuff with an external developer through team viewer for work, to interact with th CL i use terminal on OSX, when working with the developer i was always watching what they were doing and i also have all the bash history.

Usually upon opening terminal i get something like this

```
Last login: Tue Sep 17 21:33:02 on ttys001
You have mail.
unknown-5c:00:00:00:00:00:~ sam$
```

(note ive replaced some characters in the last line with 00)

But today when i opened up terminal and i get this

```
Last login: Mon Oct 21 16:49:35 on ttys000
You have mail.
richies-ipad:~ sam$
```

Note it now says richies-ipad - any idea why this is ? I dont know any one called richie let alone let them have access to my machine. Is this something to be worried about - the fact that someone has enough access to change that ?

Upon rebooting the machine i get this

```
Last login: Tue Oct 22 17:15:51 on console
You have mail.
richies-ipad:~ sam$
```

Note richies-ipad is still there.

By the way this is on my local machine.

Also what does the `ttys001` part on the first line mean ?

Comment: Have you rebooted the system? The hostname should revert to the stored configuration when it's rebooted.

Comment: Ill try it now, and let you know how i get on

Comment: I rebooted, but am still getting the same `richies-ipad` part.

Comment: When i took my computer home and ran it i got back the `unknown-5c:00:00:00:00:00:~ sam$` but now im back at the office using the office wifi, its reverted back to `richies-ipad:~ sam$`

Comment: The "ttys001" is a reference back to when we actually had teletype terminals -- it's essentially "terminal input device #1".  There are pictures on the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532413/what-is-tty-on-freebsd .

Answer (score 10):

This is nothing to worry about from a security standpoint -- it does not mean that someone named richie has access to your machine.  It may indicate networking troubles, though.  In particular, it may be difficult for you to access that machine over a network without explicitly knowing the IP.

### Hostnames

The text you're seeing there is the `hostname` for your machine, which may be set by your DNS server.  The fact that you're seeing `richies-ipad` there may mean that your DNS server thinks your current IP belongs to that machine.

Check your hostname from the terminal by typing `hostname` at the prompt.

### Setting the hostname

The easiest way to set the hostname for your machine is to rely on Mac OS X's behavior of setting the hostname equal to the computer name by default.  Go to `Apple Menu > System Preferences > Sharing` and type your desired hostname into the `Computer Name` field.

To more explicitly set the hostname, you may do so from the terminal, using the `hostname` command (i.e. `hostname <myhostname>`.  As noted in `man hostname`, though, this strategy will not survive a reboot, and you're better off using `scutil --set HostName <myhostname>` to set it.

See [This article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/24/set-the-hostname-computer-name-and-bonjour-name-separately-in-os-x/) for a more thorough explanation of the various computer names under Mac OS X.

Comment: Whats odd is that when i go to `Apple Menu > System Preferences > Sharing` i get `sam’s MacBook Pro` even though in terminal & when i run `hostname` im still getting `richies-ipad:~ sam$ hostname
richies-ipad`

Comment: Right -- you're still getting a hostname from DNS.  Have you tried setting your hostname explicitly with hostname or scutil?